# Trigger Error - Attempt to de-reference Null Object

Tags: apex, trigger, null-pointer

I'm trying to create a trigger class that will clone an Opportunity that is of a certain record type and reaches a Stage that contains Close Won.  Everything saves fine, but when I try to close out an Opp I get the error message:

*System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object: Class.ClassRenewalOppClone.cloneOpp: line 8, column 1*

Does anyone know why I might be getting this?

**Trigger Class:**

```
public class ClassRenewalOppClone {

    public void cloneOpp(List<Opportunity> cloneOpp){

    String recordTypeName = 'Renewals';
    Map<String,Schema.RecordTypeInfo> rtMapByName = Schema.SObjectType.Campaign.getRecordTypeInfosByName();
    Schema.RecordTypeInfo rtInfo =  rtMapByName.get(recordTypeName);
    id recType = rtInfo.getRecordTypeId();


        FOR(Opportunity opp1 : cloneOpp){
            IF(opp1.StageName.contains('Closed Won') && opp1.RecordTypeId == recType){
```

**Before Update Trigger:**

```
ClassRenewalOppClone updater4 = new ClassRenewalOppClone();
        updater4.cloneOpp(Trigger.new);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like rtInfo is null. Make sure you have "Renewals" record type on Campaign object.

Comment: Oh boy, that was a dumb mistake!  I need the record type for an Opportunity, not a Campaign.  Thanks for catching that!!  Now it works!